# Is there a way to have one hammer event for multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, svg, hammer.js

I am using the hammer.js touch library to run certain actions on text within an svg file.

A sample can be seen at http://codepen.io/cmgdesignstudios/pen/mebqeW

In my sample, if you tap any letter, it turns blue; the others turn black.  The following code executes this action for the first letter.

```
var Note1 =  document.getElementById('Note1');
var Note1Hammer = new Hammer (Note1);
Note1Hammer.on("tap", function(changecolor){Note1.style.fill="blue";
});
```

I have 7 different letters.  I have 7 similar blocks of code for each letter.  Can I use a single hammer variable and hammer on statement for multiple objects so that I don't have to have one for each object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I had been creating a new hammer instance for each object I wanted to use the touch library with.  However, I learned of the target option within the hammer instance which allows almost any object to receive touch recognizers within a larger group of objects such as an svg file or from the body tag of the entire html document.

```
 ev.target
 ev.target.id
```

target can be almost any object if it has an id, the id can be found with the target.id option.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the [jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js/blob/master/jquery.hammer.js) after the initial call, you can initialize it using jQuery instead.

```
hammertime = $('.note').hammer()
```